# insert more than one array using one query

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, insert

I want to insert an array of checkboxes, dropdowns, and dates into database. If I checked all the checkbox, all works fine. However, when I checked certain checkboxes, the value of checkboxes can be inserted but not the value of dropdown and date.

This is code for the checkbox, dropdown, and date:

```
<div class='field'>
    <div class='checkboxes'>
        <div class='checkbox'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='spesimen$i' name='spesimen[]' value='$JenisSpesimen' required minlength='1'/><label>$JenisSpesimen</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class='select'>
            <select id='bilangan$i' name='bilangan[]' class='med' style='display: none;'>
                <option></option>
                <option value='Pertama'>Pertama</option>
                <option value='Kedua'>Kedua</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='input' id='tarikh_ambil$i' style='display: none;'>
            <input type='text' id='tarikh_ambil_spesimen$i' name='tarikh_ambil_spesimen[]' class='small' readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this the process:

```
$spesimen = $_POST['spesimen'];         
$countSpesimen = count($_POST['spesimen']);

$bilangan = $_POST['bilangan'];
//$countBilagan = count($_POST['bilangan']);

$tarikh_ambil = $_POST['tarikh_ambil_spesimen'];    
//$countTarikh = count($_POST['tarikh_ambil_spesimen']);

for ( $x = 0; $x < $countSpesimen; $x++)
    {
        $xx = $x+1;
        $SubIDMohon = $IDMohonx.'-'.$xx;

        $dd=substr($tarikh_ambil[$x], 0, 2);
        $mm=substr($tarikh_ambil[$x], 3, 2);
        $yy=substr($tarikh_ambil[$x], 6, 4);
        $tarikh_ambil[$x] = $yy."-".$mm."-".$dd;
        if($tarikh_ambil[$x] == '--') { $tarikh_ambil[$x] = '0000-00-00'; }

        $pdo->exec("insert into simka_spesimen(IDMohon,SubIDMohon, Nama, LainLain, TarikhAmbil, TarikhHantar, TarikhMakmalTerima)
            values ('".$IDMohonx."','".$SubIDMohon."','".$spesimen[$x]."','".$bilangan[$x]."','".$tarikh_ambil[$x]."','".$tarikh_hantar_spesimen."','".$tarikh_terima_spesimen."')");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Looks like your first post. Please describe how the form data is posted to the PHP. Please include further code examples.

Comment: Also, `name='spesimen[]'` is not needed as you only have the one element. Since you do not have many elements with the same `name`, no array is created. Would advise just `name='spesimen'` and `$_POST['spesimen']`.

Comment: [ ] Value A
-dropdown list-
-date-

[ ] Value B
-dropdown list-
-date-

this is what suppose to appear. so, when i checked at Value B, the dropdown list and date did not insert into database. Only if i checked Value A, they dont have any problems

Comment: if i didnt set name as spesimen[], can i count the total of post? @Twisty

Comment: Why would you need to count it?

Comment: multiple elements can be listed after `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to wrap your fields into an common name, so that you can run a foreach over each 'fieldset' and then access its corresponding fields, instead of having them separate and independent as you have them now.

HTML would be something like this: (Implement the counter as you wish, but be sure to increment it before adding another set)

```
  <div class='field'>
    <div class='checkboxes'>
        <div class='checkbox'>
            <label><input type='checkbox' id='spesimen$i' name='fieldset[$counter][spesimen]' value='$JenisSpesimen' required minlength='1'/>$JenisSpesimen</label>
        </div>
        <div class='select'>
            <select id='bilangan$i' name='fieldset[$counter][bilangan]' class='med' style='display:none;'>
                <option></option>
                <option value='Pertama'>Pertama</option>
                <option value='Kedua'>Kedua</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='input' id='tarikh_ambil$i' style='display:none;'>
            <input type='text' id='tarikh_ambil_spesimen$i' name='fieldset[$counter][tarikh_ambil_spesimen]' class='small' readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your PHP code as follows:

```
foreach($_POST['fieldset'] as $i=>$fields){

    $SubIDMohon = $IDMohonx .'-' . ($i + 1) ;

    //If specimen is checked, the value comes with post, otherwise set it to default ''
    $specimen = ( isset($fields['specimen']) ) ? $fields['specimen'] : '';

    //check if the date is valid format
    $date = '';
    if(preg_match('^([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}$', $fields['tarikh_ambil_spesimen'])){ 
        $date = implode('-', array_reverse( explode('-', $fields['tarikh_ambil_spesimen']) ) );
    }
    else{
        $date = '0000-00-00';
    }


    $pdo->exec(
        "insert into simka_spesimen(IDMohon,SubIDMohon, Nama, LainLain, TarikhAmbil, TarikhHantar, TarikhMakmalTerima)
            values (
                '" . $IDMohonx . "',
                '" . $SubIDMohon . "',
                '" . $spesimen . "',
                '" . $fields['bilangan'] . "',
                '" . $date . "',
                '" . $tarikh_hantar_spesimen . "',
                '" . $tarikh_terima_spesimen . "'
            )"
    );
}
```

Try doing a print_r to your `$_POST` so you can see how it is structured.

Good luck!